# Apache ReWrite Rule: How to drop the parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Quick one: have a url like:
**/some.aspx?p=1&p=2**
I need to redirect to:
**/other** without any params.

I have the following:

```
RewriteRule \/some\.aspx? /other? [NC,L,R=301]
```

But I still end up with a trailing ? i.e. /other?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+some\.aspx\?p=1&p=2[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /other? [R=301,L]
```